# Docker build unexpected EOF in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, exception, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am sure I am not the only one who is interested in how to handle something like this: docker build stage in Jenkins pipeline fails with Unexpected EOF (there can be a lot of reasons, in my case the docker daemon was restarted on the slave)

```
appImage = docker.build ("${projectName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}-${gitCommit}", "--build-arg APP_ENV=${appEnv} --build-arg SKIP_LINT=true .")
```

The deploy phase kicks in, because the Unexpected EOF does not actually throw any error, there is no exception to catch so the build status is null.
I know that it's not a regular situation but still how can we handle smth like this so that the following stages do not run in case the build is interrupted.

Additional details: 
@JRichardsz , thanks for the answer! Usually currentBuild.result . defaults to null e.g. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46325 so unless you set it to success explicitly upon successful stage's execution , it will be null. But all in all the same can be achieved with try catch like :

```
if (deployableBranches.contains(env.BRANCH_NAME)) {
try {
    stage('Build image') {
      ansiColor('xterm') {
        appImage = docker.build 
("${projectName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}-${gitCommit}", "--build-arg 
SKIP_LINT=true .")
      }
    }

stage('Push image') {
  docker.withRegistry("${registryUrl}", "${dockerCredsId}") {
    appImage.push()
    appImage.push "${env.BRANCH_NAME}-latest"
  }
}

stage('Deploy') {
  build job: 'kubernetes-deploy', parameters: [
      /////
  ]
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // A shell step returns with a nonzero exit code
    // When pipeline is in a shell step, and a user presses abort
    if (e.getMessage().contains('script returned exit code 143')) {
        currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
    } else {
      currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    }
    throw e
  } finally {
    // Success or failure or abort, always send notifications
    stage('Send deployment status') {
      helpers.sendDeploymentStatus(projectName, currentBuild.result, 
      helpers.getCommitHashShort())
    }
  }
}
```

But the issue is that stage('Build image') may exit without any error code like it was in my case.

Comment: This may be fixed in docker 18.09 if it's the same error I'm thinking of: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37771

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement : "If some rule is executed in stage A, following stages must not run"

This worked for me :

```
def flag;

node {

  stage('A') { 
    flag = 1;
  }

  stage('B') { 
    // exit this stage if flag == 1
    if(flag == 1){
      return;
    } 

    //start of stage B tasks
    ...
  }

}
```

Also you could use some jenkins variable like **currentBuild.result** instead of flag like this :

```
node {

  stage('A') { 
    //stage A tasks
    //this stage could modify currentBuild.result variable
  }

  stage('B') { 
    // exit this stage if currentBuild.result is null , empty, "FAILURE", etc
    if(currentBuild.result == null || 
       currentBuild.result == "" || 
       currentBuild.result=="FAILURE" ){

      return;
    } 

    //stage B tasks
  }

}
```